# Using wildcards when mapping routes with MapWebPageRoute

Tags: razor, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

In an ASP.NET Web Pages project (not Web Forms, not MVC) I am using Mike Brind's 
[More Flexible Routing For ASP.NET Web Pages](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/187/more-flexible-routing-for-asp-net-web-pages).

I want to create a route that picks ups any number of route elements but ending in a specific word, eg:

- mydomain.com/route1/word
- mydomain.com/route1/route2/word
- mydomain.com/route1/route2/route3/word
- ...etc etc

I tried to use wildcards when mapping the route but that didn't work, eg:

`RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{*routes}/word");`

Is there a way to map these route possibilites or do I have to create a route for each possibiility, eg:

- `RouteTable.Routes.MapWebPageRoute("{route1}/word", "~/mypage.cshtml");`
- `RouteTable.Routes.MapWebPageRoute("{route1}/{route2}/word", "~/mypage.cshtml");`
- `RouteTable.Routes.MapWebPageRoute("{route1}/{route2}/{route3}/word", "~/mypage.cshtml");`
- ...etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually figured out a solution to this.

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapWebPageRoute("{*routes}",
    "~/mypage.cshtml",
    constraints: new { routes = @".*(/word)" });
```

So using constraints was the answer.